# empty log files created automatically

Tags: files

For 5 or 6 months I have been experiencing a strange activity on my android 4.1.2 device. It is samsung galaxy tab 2. The problem is somehow every day a few log files will appear in the root of my SD card and I could not figure out why and what application does it. It is very annoying as I need to clean them. I will attach a screenshot. If anyone came across the same issue, please let me know. We could try to find the solution together. If more information is needed, feel free to ask. Thank you. Vitaly.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My first guess would be an app whose initials are FW, as in the file names. Do you have such an app installed?

Comment: @DanHulme,i went through all the apps i have, and there was no with such initials. i have uninstalled some of the apps to see if this log thing continues. need to wait till next day

Answer (score 0):

Dan Hulme was correct. I did indeed have an application called "Foreca Weather" and it created the logs. It's been several days since I'd uninstalled the app, and the problem haven't showed up again. Previously I had this application for a year and didn't see any such issue till the recent update they had.